# Cant change fonts in Picker via NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, nsattributedstring

Here is my code

```
    self.fontsArray = @[@"Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN", @"Georgia", @"Times New Roman"];}

-(NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSString* str = self.fontsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:str size:13.0];
    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                    forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString* title = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:str attributes:attrsDictionary];
    return title;
}
```

I viewed the solution on this site, but anyway it doesn't work.
What is the mistake can it be?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What actually happens?

Comment: nothing happens, rows are staying with default font and size

Comment: Did you also implement the `titleForRow:` method or the `viewForRow:` method? Don't. Just implement `attributedTitleForRow:` method.

Comment: No, just only NumberOfComponents, numberOfRowsInComponent and attributedTitle

Comment: Log `title` just before returning it. Make sure it has the expect font. If not, do some debugging to determine why.

Comment: 015-04-11 20:38:22.684 CyberSecurityDigest[90178:7624727] Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb181e31170> font-family: \"HiraKakuProN-W3\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 10.00pt";

Comment: title is correct, but the same font is displayed with the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
NSString* str = [[CSDMainManager sharedManager].fontsArray objectAtIndex:row];
if (!tView){
    tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:str size:20.0];
    tView.font =font;
}
tView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];
return tView;
```

}